# ggplot2: how to set scale labels function based on value in data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plotting function that will be passed different data where some needs a percent scale and others need a comma scale.

I have included a column in the data that specifies which scale is to be used.

How can I write the `scale_y_continuous()` line to use that value for the label?

```r
library(tidyverse)


mymt <- mtcars %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(value = value * 10) %>%
  mutate(varscale = if_else(name == "disp", "comma", "percent")) %>% 
  filter(name == "disp")

#Attempt 1:
mymt %>% 
  {ggplot(., aes(x = rn, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = . %>% distinct(varscale) %>% pull(varscale))
  }
#> Error in UseMethod("distinct"): no applicable method for 'distinct' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"


#Attempt 2:
myscale <- mymt %>% distinct(varscale) %>% pull(varscale) 
myscale <- sym(paste0("scales::", myscale))

mymt %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = rn, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = myscale)
#> Error: Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

[image]

```r
#Desired outcome:
mtcars %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(value = value * 10) %>%
  mutate(varscale = if_else(name == "disp", "comma", "percent")) %>% 
  filter(name == "disp") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = rn, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
#> Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels): object 'comma' not found
```

Comment: does `comma_format` work if you replaced `comma`?

Comment: @RyanJohn no it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

We could use `.data`

```
mymt %>% 
   {ggplot(., aes(x = rn, y = value)) +
   geom_point() +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = unique(.data[['varscale']]))
   }
```

Comment: > mymt %>% 
+   {ggplot(., aes(x = rn, y = value)) +
+   geom_point() +
+   scale_y_continuous(labels = unique(.data[['varscale']]))
+   }
Error: Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @jzadra i am not getting that error though

Comment: Odd.  I've pasted your exact code and still get that error.  The rlange::last_error() is "<error/rlang_error>
Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context.
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 7. rlang:::`[[.rlang_fake_data_pronoun`(.data, "varscale")
 8. rlang:::stop_fake_data_subset()
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context."

Comment: Could be related to package version

Comment: I'm using ggplot2 version 3.3.5

Comment: I used 3.3.3 though

Comment: Requires rlang. For extending ggplot2 in package development, I was searching for a ggplot2 solution to transform data in a breaks function of a new using scale_x_...().